# Strings formatting in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have to write a program in python that prompts for a phone number of 10 digits and two dashes,with dashes after the area code and next three numbers.Also to diplay if the phone number is valid format or not

Comment: Is there anything you have already? Because you should, if you decided to write here. We don't do the job for you. We help in specific programming issues, so we expect you to be specific. Just post the code that you expected to work but it didn't.

Comment: That's awesome you have such task, but why do you post it here? It looks like a Facebook status rather than a question. Actually there's even not a question at all.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a short program here which does what you need.

```
def main():
    phone_number= input('Please enter a phone number in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX: ')
    x = validNumber(phone_number)
    print x
def validNumber(phone_number):
    for j,k in enumerate(phone_number):
        if j in [3,7]:
            if k != '-':
                phone_number=input('Please enter a valid phone number: ')
            return phone_number
        elif not c.isalnum():
            phone_number=input('Please enter a valid phone number: ')
            return phone_number
    return phone_number
```

It will continually ask the user to put in the write one, until he does.